# WPF/Powershell form GUI working on Win11 machines but not Win 10

Tags: wpf, powershell

This is a powershell GUI MP3 player. This is a smaller half broken version, the real script is starting to get on the larger side, which makes it less attractive to look at to help, so I am showing an older version missing lots of features and fixes. Maybe someone can help take a quick peek.

Again, regardless of other issues someone could point out, this will work on 11 and not on 10 and I'm curious why.

If you wanted to look at the full latest script (Which works fine on 11 but not on 10) You can check here: https://github.com/illsk1lls/PowerPlayer

```
$global:Playing=0
$global:tracking=0
$global:icurrent=-1
function Update-Gui{
$window.Dispatcher.Invoke([Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority]::Background, [action]{})
}
function dropDownMenu(){
    Switch($MenuFile.Visibility){
        'Visible'{
            $MenuMain.BorderBrush='#111111'
            $MenuFile.Visibility='Collapsed'
            $MenuFolder.Visibility='Collapsed'
            $MenuExit.Visibility='Collapsed'
        }
        'Collapsed'{
            $MenuMain.BorderBrush='#CCCCCC'
            $MenuFile.Visibility='Visible'
            $MenuFolder.Visibility='Visible'
            $MenuExit.Visibility='Visible'
        }
    }
}
function TogglePlayButton(){
    if($files -ne $null){
        Switch($global:Playing){
            0{
                $PlayImage.Source='.\resources\Pause.png'
                $mediaPlayer.Play()
                $global:Playing=1
                $StatusInfo.Text="Now Playing:"
                $BG.Play()
            }
            1{
                $PlayImage.Source='.\resources\Play.png'
                $mediaPlayer.Pause()
                $global:Playing=0
                $StatusInfo.Text="Paused:"
                $BG.Pause()
            }
        }
    }
}
function NextTrack(){
    if($icurrent -lt $files.Length - 1){
    $global:icurrent++
    $file = $files[$icurrent]
    PlayTrack
    }
}
function PrevTrack(){
    if($icurrent -ge 1){
    $global:icurrent--
    $file = $files[$icurrent]
    PlayTrack
    }
}
function trackLength(){
    $Shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
    $FolderL = $shell.Namespace($(Split-Path $FullName))
    $FileL = $FolderL.ParseName($(Split-Path $FullName -Leaf))
    [int]$h, [int]$m, [int]$s = ($FolderL.GetDetailsOf($FileL, 27)).split(":")
    $global:totaltime=$h*60*60 + $m*60 +$s
    $ReadableTotal=[timespan]::fromseconds($totaltime)
    $TimerB.Text=("{0:mm\:ss}" -f $ReadableTotal)
    $global:PositionSlider.Maximum=$totaltime
}
function WaitForSong(){
    while(([Math]::Ceiling(([TimeSpan]::Parse($mediaPlayer.Position)).TotalSeconds)) -lt ([ref] $script:totaltime).Value){
        if(([ref] $script:tracking).Value -eq 0){
            $PositionSlider.Value=([TimeSpan]::Parse($mediaPlayer.Position)).TotalSeconds
            $TimePassed=[timespan]::fromseconds(([TimeSpan]::Parse($mediaPlayer.Position)).TotalSeconds)
            $TimerA.Text=("{0:mm\:ss}" -f $TimePassed)
        }
        Update-Gui
        Start-Sleep -milliseconds 50
    }
}
function PlayTrack(){
    $mediaPlayer.Position=New-Object System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    $FullName="$path\$file"
    $mediaPlayer.open($FullName)
    $CurrentTrack.Text=[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
    $mediaPlayer.Play()
    trackLength
    WaitForSong 
}
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework, System.Drawing, System.Windows.Forms, WindowsFormsIntegration, presentationCore
[xml]$xaml='
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="PowerPlayer" Height="180" Width="300" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="#111111" BorderThickness="10" Background="#111111">
        <Grid Name="MainWindow">
            <MediaElement Name="BG" Height="160" Width="280" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Stretch="Fill" SpeedRatio="1" IsMuted="True"/>
            <Canvas>
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="32" Canvas.Top="40" Foreground="#CCCCCC">
                    <TextBlock.Inlines>
                        <Run Name="Status" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                    </TextBlock.Inlines>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Name="CurrentTrack" Canvas.Top="69" Foreground="#CCCCCC" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Text="No Media Loaded" TextAlignment="Center" Width="280"/>
                <Button Name="Menu" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" FontSize="10" BorderBrush="#111111" Foreground="#CCCCCC" Background="#111111" Height="18" Width="50">Menu</Button>
                <Button Name="minWin" Canvas.Left="236" Canvas.Top="0" FontSize="10" BorderBrush="#111111" Foreground="#CCCCCC" Background="#111111" Height="18" Width="22">___</Button>
                <Button Name="X" Canvas.Left="258" Canvas.Top="0" FontSize="10" BorderBrush="#111111" Foreground="#CCCCCC" Background="#111111" Height="18" Width="22" FontWeight="Bold">X</Button>
                <Button Name="File" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="17" FontSize="10" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" Foreground="#CCCCCC" Background="#111111" Height="18" Width="90" Visibility="Collapsed">Open File</Button>
                <Button Name="Folder" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="34" FontSize="10" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" Foreground="#CCCCCC" Background="#111111" Height="18" Width="90" Visibility="Collapsed">Open Folder</Button>
                <Button Name="Exit" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="51" FontSize="10" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" Foreground="#CCCCCC" Background="#111111" Height="18" Width="90" Visibility="Collapsed">Exit</Button>
                <Button Name="Prev" Canvas.Left="39" Canvas.Top="119" BorderBrush="#2F539B" Background="#728FCE" Opacity="0.9">
                    <Button.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Resources>
                    <Image Name="PrevButton" Height="23" Width="40"></Image>
                </Button>
                <Button Name="Play" Canvas.Left="116" Canvas.Top="119" BorderBrush="#2F539B" Background="#728FCE" Opacity="0.9">
                    <Button.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Resources>
                    <Image Name="PlayButton" Height="23" Width="50"></Image>
                </Button>
                <Button Name="Next" Canvas.Left="199" Canvas.Top="119" BorderBrush="#2F539B" Background="#728FCE" Opacity="0.9">
                    <Button.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Resources>
                    <Image Name="NextButton" Height="23" Width="40"></Image>
                </Button>
                <Slider Name="Volume" Canvas.Left="179" Canvas.Top="45" Height="6" Width="60" Orientation="Horizontal" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" SmallChange=".01" LargeChange=".1" Background="#728FCE" Opacity="0.9" />
                <Slider Name="Position" Canvas.Left="54" Canvas.Top="100" Height="6" Width="173" Orientation="Horizontal" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Background="#728FCE" Opacity="0.9" />
                <TextBlock Name="TimerA" Canvas.Left="18" Canvas.Top="95" Foreground="#CCCCCC" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBlock Name="TimerB" Canvas.Left="233" Canvas.Top="95" Foreground="#CCCCCC" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
        <TaskbarItemInfo/>
    </Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
</Window>'
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
$window.Title='PowerPlayer'
$mediaPlayer=New-Object system.windows.media.mediaplayer
$mediaPlayer.Add_MediaEnded({
    $mediaPlayer.Stop()
    $mediaPlayer.Position=New-Object System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    $PositionSlider.Value=([TimeSpan]::Parse($mediaPlayer.Position)).TotalSeconds
    $PlayImage.Source='.\resources\Play.png'
    $CurrentTrack.Text='No Media Loaded'
    $global:Playing=0
    $global:icurrent=-1
    $StatusInfo.Text=''
    $TimerA.Text=''
    $TimerB.Text='' 
})
$window.Add_Closing({[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Exit();Stop-Process $pid})
$VolumeSlider=$Window.FindName("Volume")
$VolumeSlider.Value=$mediaPlayer.Volume
$VolumeSlider.Add_PreviewMouseUp({
    $mediaPlayer.Volume=$VolumeSlider.Value
})
$PositionSlider=$Window.FindName("Position")
$PositionSlider.Add_PreviewMouseUp({
    $mediaPlayer.Position=("{0:hh\:mm\:ss\.fff}" -f ([timespan]::fromseconds([Math]::Truncate($PositionSlider.Value))))
    $global:tracking=0
})
$PositionSlider.Add_PreviewMouseDown({
    $global:tracking=1
})
$BG=$Window.FindName("BG")
$FullBGPath=[IO.Path]::GetFullPath(".\resources\bg.gif")
$BG.Source=$FullBGPath
$BG.Add_MediaEnded({
    $BG.Stop()
    $BG.Position=New-Object System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
    $BG.Play()
})
$bitmap=New-Object System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage
$bitmap=$BG.Source
$window.Icon=$bitmap
$window.TaskbarItemInfo.Overlay=$bitmap
$window.TaskbarItemInfo.Description=$window.Title
$window.add_MouseLeftButtonDown({
$window.DragMove()
})
$StatusInfo=$Window.FindName("Status")
$StatusInfo.Text=''
$CurrentTrack=$Window.FindName("CurrentTrack")
$TimerA=$Window.FindName("TimerA")
$TimerB=$Window.FindName("TimerB")
$MenuMain=$Window.FindName("Menu")
$MenuMain.Add_MouseEnter({
    $MenuMain.Background="#CCCCCC"
    $MenuMain.Foreground="#111111"
})
$MenuMain.Add_MouseLeave({
    $MenuMain.Background="#111111"
    $MenuMain.Foreground="#CCCCCC"
})
$MenuMain.Add_Click({
    dropDownMenu
})
$MenuFile=$Window.FindName("File")
$MenuFile.Add_MouseEnter({
    $MenuFile.Background="#CCCCCC"
    $MenuFile.Foreground="#111111"
})
$MenuFile.Add_MouseLeave({
    $MenuFile.Background="#111111"
    $MenuFile.Foreground="#CCCCCC"
})
$MenuFile.Add_Click({
    dropDownMenu
    $getFile=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
        InitialDirectory="$env:UserProfile\Music"
        Title='Select a MP3 file...'
        Filter='MP3 (*.mp3)|*.mp3'
    }
    $null=$getFile.ShowDialog()
    $file=$getFile.Filename
    $path = Split-Path $file -Parent
    $path = $path+'\'
    $files=@()
    $files+=Split-Path $file -leaf
    $mediaPlayer.Position=New-Object System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    $CurrentTrack.Text=[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
    TogglePlayButton
    NextTrack
})
$MenuFolder=$Window.FindName("Folder")
$MenuFolder.Add_MouseEnter({
    $MenuFolder.Background="#CCCCCC"
    $MenuFolder.Foreground="#111111"
})
$MenuFolder.Add_MouseLeave({
    $MenuFolder.Background="#111111"
    $MenuFolder.Foreground="#CCCCCC"
})
$MenuFolder.Add_Click({
    dropDownMenu
    $folder = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $folder.SelectedPath = "$env:UserProfile\Music"
    $null = $folder.ShowDialog()
    $path = $folder.SelectedPath
    $files=@()
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.mp3 -File -Name| ForEach-Object {
        $files+=$_
    }
    TogglePlayButton
    while(([ref] $script:icurrent).Value -lt $files.Length - 1){
        NextTrack
    }
})
$MenuExit=$Window.FindName("Exit")
$MenuExit.Add_MouseEnter({
    $MenuExit.Background="#CCCCCC"
    $MenuExit.Foreground="#111111"
})
$MenuExit.Add_MouseLeave({
    $MenuExit.Background="#111111"
    $MenuExit.Foreground="#CCCCCC"
})
$MenuExit.Add_Click({
    Exit
})
$minWin=$Window.FindName("minWin")
$minWin.Add_MouseEnter({
    $minWin.Background="#CCCCCC"
    $minWin.Foreground="#111111"
})
$minWin.Add_MouseLeave({
    $minWin.Background="#111111"
    $minWin.Foreground="#CCCCCC"
})
$minWin.Add_Click({
    $Window.WindowState='Minimized'
})
$Xbutton=$Window.FindName("X")
$Xbutton.Add_MouseEnter({
    $Xbutton.Background="#CCCCCC"
    $Xbutton.Foreground="#ff0000"
})
$Xbutton.Add_MouseLeave({
    $Xbutton.Background="#111111"
    $Xbutton.Foreground="#CCCCCC"
})
$Xbutton.Add_Click({
    Exit
})
$Prev=$Window.FindName("Prev")
$PrevImage=$Window.FindName("PrevButton")
$PrevImage.Source='.\resources\Prev.png'
$Prev.Add_Click({
    $checkposition=$mediaPlayer.Position.ToString()
    [int]$checkposition=$checkposition.Replace("(?=[.]).*",'').Replace(':','')
        if($global:Playing -eq 0){
            if($icurrent -ge 1){
            $global:icurrent--
            $file = $files[$icurrent]
            $mediaPlayer.Position=New-Object System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            $FullName="$path\$file"
            $mediaPlayer.open($FullName)
            $CurrentTrack.Text=[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
            trackLength
            WaitForSong 
            }           
        } else {
        if($checkposition -le 2){
            PrevTrack
        } else {
            $mediaPlayer.Position=New-Object System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        }
    }
})
$Play=$Window.FindName("Play")
$PlayImage=$Window.FindName("PlayButton")
$PlayImage.Source='.\resources\Play.png'
$Play.Add_Click({
    TogglePlayButton
})
$Next=$Window.FindName("Next")
$NextImage=$Window.FindName("NextButton")
$NextImage.Source='.\resources\Next.png'
$Next.Add_Click({
    if($global:Playing -eq 0){
        if($icurrent -lt $files.Length - 1){
        $global:icurrent++
        $file = $files[$icurrent]
        $mediaPlayer.Position=New-Object System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        $FullName="$path\$file"
        $mediaPlayer.open($FullName)
        $CurrentTrack.Text=[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
        trackLength
        WaitForSong 
        }
    } else {
        NextTrack
    }
})
$BG.Play()
$window.Show()
$BG.Pause()
$appContext=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext
[void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($appContext)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a scope issue.

ref cannot be used with $script: on Win 10, but can on 11, even though it is probably incorrect either way

```
([ref] $script:totaltime)
```

to fix the issue I simply removed the $script: reference

```
([ref] $totaltime)
```